# Bin packing with a twist?

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been trying to look for some sort of an algorithm that will take care of the problem i have. The closest thing that i've come across is that of a bin packing algorithm but i don't think its quiet what i'm looking for.

This document is a graphical representation of my problem and the expected output:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/90871434/Rectangles

My thoughts where to find the lowest(height) rectangle and create a rectangle that fits the width of the remaining rectangles, and with some recursion figure out the rest.

What i'm basically trying to do is find the smallest amount of vertically stacked rectangles, given N amount of horizontally placed rectangles.

Doing this in Java i have a HashMap with the input rectangles.

Any ideas, code, links ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use *divide and conquer*.

When you find the lowest rectangle you also split your data set. The next rectangles are either exclusively in the left or right set. And that works recursively.

Answer (score 2):

Find the smallest rectangle.

Create your first resulting rectangle out of that.

Determine the remaining rectangles.

Apply the algorithm on all continuous groups of remaining rectangles.

Comment: Ah yes that's the same line of thinking i had. The problem is the algorithm part of it as in the code that would traverse through the HashMap and ultimately place the rectangles in the right place.

Comment: A much more obvious representation is an array of rectangles arranged from left to right.  With that representation, it is much easier to implement the above algorithm.  It's worst case will be `O(n*n)` and its average will be `O(n log(n))`.  If that algorithm is not fast enough, I have a more complex one that is O(n log(n))` worst case.  But the complexity is probably not warranted.